# Cygwin: Run a script in mintty/bash

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin, context-menu

*Initially asked on SO.com, but I closed it. I think it better fits SU.com. Please tell me if it is also not the right place.*

I want to add a context menu to a .sh file to run it in cygwin.

I tried to manipulate the default "Open Cygwin here" command:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe "%L"
```

Unfortunately, all I get is a window that closes again immediately.
Also, I am not 100% sure, what is the purpose and the meaning of the arguments of xhere.

This is working:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe %1
```

But I'd like to have mintty as terminal window.

Final Question:
**Is there a way to add a command string to be executed to the "Open Cygwin here" string?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @vaz_az for keeping me motivated.

The problem with cygwin is, that it requires POSIX style paths.

This means that you have to translate the file parameter `%1` that is supplied by windows.
This can be done using the `cygpath` tool. The following code shows a 1-liner that can be used as command in regedit:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/bash -l -c '$(/bin/cygpath "%1")'
```

In the following line, there are some examples, what can be done with a 1-liner:

```
#Simple
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -e bash -l -c '$(cygpath "%1")'

#Fire and Forget (With 1 second delay at the end to read any messages)
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -e bash -l -c '$(cygpath "%1"); echo DONE; sleep 1'

#With logging to static file
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -l C:\cygwin\home\Nippey\cygwin.log -e /bin/bash -l -c '$(cygpath "%1")'

#With interactive shell after execution (Unfortunately the -i parameter of bash does not work together with -c, so you have to start a sub-shell)
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/bash -l -c '$(cygpath "%1"); bash'
```

Comment: `$(cygpath "%1")` will not work with paths that contain a space. Use `$(cygpath -ms "%1")` instead.

Comment: Nice finding. I won't pull it into my answer, because depending on how your HDD has been formatted, the old 8.3 format might be unsupported.
Anyway: For me it works even without the `-ms` switch! This is my console then: `Starting /bin/bash.exe  >>  xxx@xxx /cygdrive/c/Program Files` I think it is a question of setting the right quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the following command : `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/bash -l -c '%1'`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It actually didn't solve my problem, as Cygwin expects Linux "/" paths and not M$ "\" paths. But you pushed my motivation to try harder! I will add a separate answer.

Comment: To be more exact, using your answer leads to `/bin/bash: C:cygwinhomeNippeytest.sh: command not found`